# Add together grouped rows into one value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've got an issue where I've been presented data in this format from SQL, and have directly imported that into SSRS 2008.

I do have access to the stored procedure for this report, however I don't want to change it as a few other reports rely on it.

```
Project HoursSpent  Cost
1       5           45
1       8           10
1       7           25
1       5           25
2       1           15
2       3           10
2       5           15
2       6           10
3       6           10
3       4           5
3       4           10
3       2           5
```

I've been struggling all morning to understand how/when I should be implementing the SUM() function with this.
I have tried already to SUM() the rows, but it still outputs the above result.

Should I be adding any extra groups?

Ideally, I need to have the following output:

```
Project HoursSpent  Cost
1       25          105
2       15          40
3       16          30
```

**EDIT:** Here is my current structure:

[image]

"LineName" is a group for each project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a row group on "Project" since you want to sum up the data per each project.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my current structure. I already have one group for each project. Do you mean to say, I should add another? Or should this one do already?

Comment: You should remove the Details grouping and only leave the LineName group

Comment: You're welcome! The Details grouping you could have used to show all the rows and then add a Total Row(by right click on Details -> Add Total -> After) to show the sum per Project